# fwrite() output a file with \r\n instead of \n

Tags: php, base64, decode

I have a string of base64 image and I use `base64_decode` to get image bytes. After, I use `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` to save the file in server. But the file output gets the \r\n, and the image gets corrupted. When I use `preg_replace("\r\n", "\n")` nothing happens.

**Base64 Image String:**

```
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
```

**Code:**

```
$imageBytes = base64_decode($base64Image);

$file = fopen($path, $imageBytes);
fwrite($file, $imageBytes);
fclose($file);
```

**Original image bytes:**

[image: Original Image]

**Decoded image bytes:**

[image: Decoded image]

> When I put in my `localhost` server (WAMP) it works! But in the web server, not.

Comment: `preg_replace("\r\n", "\n")` is invalid usage, is that just pseudo code or your actual code?

Comment: you may have meant to use `str_replace("\r\n", "\n")`

Comment: I've tried with `preg_replace("/\r\n/", "\n")` and now with `str_replace("\r\n", "\n")`, but nothing happens. :( The code `preg_replace("/r/n", "/n")` is a pseudo code, sorry chris85!

Comment: make sure the permissions to write to it and the folder it's in are set properly then. Does http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php throw anything back?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The permission of folder is 777 (for tests!). I can write the file, the problem is: the saved file is with \r\n instead of \n in the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You should open your file in [binary mode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). This prevents certain OSes translating your newlines.

```
$img = base64_decode($the_string);
$f = fopen('img.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($f, $img);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's makes a lot of sense, but not worked! Is there any configuration to php server?

Comment: I tested on Unix, the above code works for me. What platform does it not run on?

Comment: My OS is Debian. I don't know why it's not working... :(